# ask user to write file name before downloading txt file in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to download content in a txt file. belwo is the sample code

```js
download() {
let content = "Sample text";
saveAs(new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain'}), 'sample.txt');
```

I am using file-saver lib to downlaod the content.
all works fine but i need to open the browser popup where user can write/override the file name before downloading it and choose the directory as well where user will save the file.

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [showSaveFilePicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showSaveFilePicker)

Answer (score 1):

Before directly calling the `saveAs()` function upon click of the button to download the content, probably you can call a prompt to get the name, and then resume the rest.

```js
download() {
    let filename = window.prompt('Please enter a name for your file', 'sample');
    let content = "Sample text";
    saveAs(new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain'}), `${filename}.txt`);
}
```

Or to be more stylish, if you use Bootstrap, you can make use of [modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), or any stylish modal of your own.

Comment: I need to implement the default pop up. same way when we import any file

Comment: That's what I explained Raj. You can prompt for a file name, and use it to download. Just replace the file name in your `saveAs` method. I've updated the answer with example.

Comment: updated the question. i missed to add i need user to choose the directory as well

Comment: I don't think that is possible with file-saver package. This is what they say in [issues](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/42) Hope this answers all your questions :)

Comment: Do we have any other way apart from file-saver so that we can show the default popup to write file name and select directory

Comment: According to my understanding, no package or option supports this option because of browser restrictions. In my opinion. why can't you simply leave it to the users to choose? For example, in Chrome, go to Settings > Advanced > Downloads > Enable "Ask where to save each file before downloading". For users who don't do this, the file will be saved in default directory.